# Javascript function plays correctly old site but not new

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

I recently moved my companies website to one of our unused web servers in order to update the Joomla backend from 1.5.26 to the latest Joomla 2.5. We couldn't go to 3.x because of modules.I used SP Upgrade, and everything migrated brilliantly once I had my new theme and current modules installed.

We have a customized default theme and an assigned theme to the home page. Within the assigned theme (assigned to the home menu) directory, index.php has a script above the header. I will post this code below.

The old site can be found at the following link and when you first go to the site, you will see the video play.
cpmchurchministries.com/old

The new site can be found at the following link and when you first go to the site, you will see only an image.
cpmchurchministries.com/new

The code is the same for both sites, index.php:

```
<head>
    <jdoc:include type="head" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/template.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/swf/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        swfobject.embedSWF("<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/chosenpeople/swf/cpm_logo.swf", "flash_logo", "245", "162", "7");
        window.addEvent('domready', function() {
            if($('default_header')) {
                if(Cookie.get("cpm_movie") != "full") {
                    full_movie();
                } else {
                    small_movie();
                }
            }
        });

        function small_movie() {
            $('default_header').removeClass('full_movie');
            $('default_header').addClass('small_movie');
            swfobject.embedSWF("<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/cphome/swf/header_home.swf", "flash_header", "696", "157", "7");
        }

    function full_movie() {
        $('default_header').removeClass('small_movie');
        $('default_header').addClass('full_movie');
        Cookie.set("cpm_movie", "full", {duration: 365});
        swfobject.embedSWF("<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/cphome/swf/video_header.swf", "flash_header", "696", "400", "7");
    }
</script>
<?php if ($editmode) echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$this->baseurl.'/templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css" />'."\n"; ?>
```

Has anyone run into a similar issue? Is it possible to get any help?
Thank you. . .

Comment: You're getting errors in the console; something about `Cookie.get()`.

Comment: The old site was off line, it should be accessible now. 
cpmchurchministries.com/old

Let me know if you can see it now. 

I will look through all your responses, and see what was suggested now.
Thank you all so much for responding!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newer version of Joomla that you are using uses a newer version of the MooTools library so you need to make the following two function changes to the code:

---

OLD

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    if($('default_header')) {
        if(Cookie.get("cpm_movie") != "full") {
            full_movie();
        } else {
            small_movie();
        }
    }
});


function small_movie() {
    $('default_header').removeClass('full_movie');
    $('default_header').addClass('small_movie');
    swfobject.embedSWF("/new/templates/cphome/swf/header_home.swf", "flash_header", "696", "157", "7");
}

function full_movie() {
    $('default_header').removeClass('small_movie');
    $('default_header').addClass('full_movie');
    Cookie.set("cpm_movie", "full", {duration: 365});
    swfobject.embedSWF("/new/templates/cphome/swf/video_header.swf", "flash_header", "696", "400", "7");
}
```

---

NEW

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {    
  if($('default_header')) {
            if(Cookie.read("cpm_movie") != "full") {
                full_movie();
            } else {
                small_movie();
            }
        }
    });

function small_movie() {
    $('default_header').removeClass('full_movie');
    $('default_header').addClass('small_movie');
    swfobject.embedSWF("/new/templates/cphome/swf/header_home.swf", "flash_header", "696", "157", "7");
}
function full_movie() {
    $('default_header').removeClass('small_movie');
    $('default_header').addClass('full_movie');
    Cookie.write("cpm_movie", "full", {duration: 365});
    swfobject.embedSWF("/new/templates/cphome/swf/video_header.swf", "flash_header", "696", "400", "7");
}
```

**EDIT** for easy copy paste

Comment: Hello, I changed the cookie code as you suggested from "get to read" and from "set to write". I looked closely at the code, am I missing any other changes from above?

Comment: I just checked the url cpmchurchministries.com/new it still has the old code

Comment: Ok, let me see one other spot. Maybe I have to change this in two different spots since I have two different theme templates working together.

Comment: It appears that you changed the code but added the old and new versions of full_movie() and replaced the function small_movie(). After this the code is back in its original state. Please make only the changes I have indicated.

Comment: I have made an edit so that you can copy paste it easily

Comment: You are a genius! :-) THANK YOU!!!! I edited it directly after uploading my backup file.

Answer (score 0):

I have this error on your "new site" :
GET http://cdn.wibiya.com/Toolbars/dir_0775/Toolbar_775982/Loader_775982.js 403 (Forbidden)

I can't access the "old site", there is a Joomla login page. It would be easier if we could access it to compare both sites.

Comment: I fixed the access to the "old" site

Answer (score 0):

As Pointy said, you are getting some errors in the Javascript console:

1. Uncaught TypeError: Object function
   (){e(this);if(g.$prototyping){return this;}this.$caller=null;var
   i=(this.initialize)?this.initialize.apply(this,arguments):this;this.$caller=this.caller=null;
   return i;} has no method 'get' (index):27
2. GET
   http://cdn.wibiya.com/Toolbars/dir_0775/Toolbar_775982/Loader_775982.js
   403 (Forbidden) (index):249
3. Uncaught ReferenceError: JCaption is not defined (index):17
4. GET http://cpmchurchministries.com/main/flash/menorah_shine.swf 404
   (Not Found)

When there are errors with Javascript, the flow is stopped, so your image on the header is not replaced by the video (is not a "video", it's a flash swf movie).

One of the offending codes are:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('load', function() {
                new JCaption('img.caption');
            });
  </script>
```

If you cannot remove this code, Try this [link](http://joomlavisually.com/tips/remove-jcaption-code.html) to get rid of the JCaption problem and try again your site.

By the way, to see the errors on the console, try using a Chrome Browser, Tools, Javascript console (a must for every webdev!)

Comment: Hello, thank you.I am looking through the index.php code which I have access to. I don't see that specific code you pasted above. I am wondering if this is within a different index.php file

Comment: I went to the link you provided, and I did option 3 and Edit the Joomla! Core

In the file components/com_content/controller.php (on line 51 in Joomla! 2.5.1), remove this line of code:

JHtml::_('behavior.caption');